# CSV import to QGIS 2.18.00 - QGIS only shows 9 of 14 points

Tags: qgis, csv, import

I'm trying to import a csv file into QGIS 2.18.00. The attributes and thus coordinates inside of QGIS are displayed just fine but QGIS only shows 9 of 14 imported points. I checked the coordinates with googlemaps, they work fine there. I exported the csv with python so I tried different delimiters and converted the coordinates to a string and integer, which shows the exact same results for all my approaches.

Screenshots:

[image: Import csv]

( It says I cannot share more than two links so I had to cut out 2 screenshots which shows a) 9/14 points on the map and b) the complete attribute table inside of QGIS)

You can find the original CSV File here:
http://txt.do/dk57u

Comment: You have 14 points, but 5 points are overlapping...(plotted at the same location).

Comment: How is it possible, that one man can be so stupid as I am? This is pretty awkward. Thank you, sir!

Comment: One of those things...I do every once in so often.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have 14 points, but 5 points are overlapping...(plotted at the same location).

Overlapping features are really difficult to detect. I honestly have no good idea how to deal with this problem, without prior knowledge that they are located at the same place.

[image]

One way to double-check is to sort the csv by its Latitude or Longitude, but this is just an afterwit.

Comment: +1, one of the methods I use to check for duplicates is to use the **Topology Checker** plugin. If you configure this, you can select a layer and choose the rule `must not have duplicates`. Add this rule then click _OK_ and _Validate All_ which should highlight which features have duplicated geometries :)

Comment: Thanks @Joseph I have not had used Topology Checker yet, but sounds promising. (There are several tools with similar names, and I have been just hesitant... ) Will do try it.

Comment: What about labelling the points? Then you get two labels placed automatically so that they don't overlap.

Comment: A quick possibility to check the feature count is to right-click on the layer and select "Show feature count". Also, this is more efficient than counting in case of >10 points ;).
Ad overlapping features (and their selection): There is some discussion about this on the qgis user mailing list: https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-user/2017-May/040101.html